# How to check if specific set of ID's exists?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, ansi-sql

I have a source table (piece of it):

```
+--------------------+
|  E M P L O Y E E   |
+--------------------+
| ID |   EQUIPMENT   |
+--------------------+
| 1  | tv,car,phone  |
| 2  | car,phone     |
| 3  | tv,phone      |
+----+---------------+
```

After normalization process I ended with two new tables:

```
+----------------+
| DICT_EQUIPMENT |
+----------------+
| ID | EQUIPMENT |
+----------------+
| 1  | tv        |
| 2  | car       |
| 3  | phone     |
+----+-----------+

+---------------------+
|    SET_EQUIPMENT    |
+----+--------+-------+
| ID | SET_ID | EQ_ID |
+----+--------+-------+
| 1  |   1    |   1   |
| 2  |   1    |   2   |
| 3  |   1    |   3   |
| 4  |   2    |   2   |
| 5  |   2    |   3   |
| 6  |   3    |   1   |
| 7  |   3    |   3   |
+----+--------+-------+

(the piece/part)
+-----------------+
| E M P L O Y E E |
+-----------------+
| ID | EQ_SET_ID  |
+-----------------+
| 1  |     1      |
| 2  |     2      |
| 3  |     3      |
+----+------------+
```

And now when I want to find correct `SET_ID` I can write something like this:

```
SELECT SET_ID
  FROM SET_EQUIPMENT S1,
       SET_EQUIPMENT S2,
       SET_EQUIPMENT S3
 WHERE S1.SET_ID = S2.SET_ID
   AND S2.SET_ID = S3.SET_ID
   AND S1.EQ_ID = 1
   AND S2.EQ_ID = 2
   AND S3.EQ_ID = 3;
```

Maybe any ideas for optimize this query? how find the correct set?

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to do in your query? It doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: Not clear what is your required output please add in to the question.

Comment: What database are you using?  MySQL or Postgres?

Comment: Unusually, I think you've over-normalized!! Nothing wrong with that per se, but it can make queries unnecessarily complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use explicit `join` syntax for the method you are using:

```
SELECT S1.SET_ID
FROM SET_EQUIPMENT S1 JOIN
     SET_EQUIPMENT S2
     ON S1.SET_ID = S2.SET_ID JOIN
     SET_EQUIPMENT S3
     ON S2.SET_ID = S3.SET_ID
 WHERE S1.EQ_ID = 1 AND
       S2.EQ_ID = 2 AND
       S3.EQ_ID = 3;
```

Commas in a `from` clause are quite outdated.  (And, this fixes a syntax error in your query.)

An alternative method is to use `group by` with a `having` clause:

```
SELECT S.SET_ID
FROM SET_EQUIPMENT S
GROUP BY S.SET_ID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN S.EQ_ID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN S.EQ_ID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN S.EQ_ID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

Which method works better depends on a number of factors -- for instance, the database engine you are using, the size of the tables, the indexes on the tables.  You have to test which method works better on your system.

Answer (score 1):

You've normalised wrongly. Get rid of `set_equipment`
Change to have three tables: employee, equipment, employee_equipment.

If you're looking for the equipment for a given employee you want to use:

```
select id, equipment
from equipment eq
inner join employee_equipment ee on eq.id = ee.eq_id
inner join employee emp on emp.id = ee.emp_id
where emp.id = 2
```